# Find index of largest elements

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to find the index of each of the four largest elements in an array.

Note: - What I need is position of the elements I don't need to sort them.

Comment: what kind of array do you have? one-dimmenstion, two-dimmentsion?

Comment: nopes, this is powerpoint vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through them and keep track of the four largest is the only way.  I can't think of anything more efficient than an O(n) operation.

I think this would work.  It will give you an array containing a variable number of largest indices:

```
Function GetLargestIndices(inArray() As Integer, numIndices As Integer) As Integer()
    ReDim returnArray(numIndices) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(returnArray)
        returnArray(i) = -1
    Next

    For i = 0 To UBound(inArray)
        For j = UBound(returnArray) To 0 Step -1
            If (returnArray(j) = -1) Then
                returnArray(j) = i
                Exit For
            ElseIf (inArray(i) > inArray(returnArray(j))) Then
                If (j > 0) Then
                    For k = 0 To j
                        returnArray(k) = returnArray(k + 1)
                    Next
                End If

                returnArray(j) = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    GetLargestIndices = returnArray
End Function
```

Here's a way to test it:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim testArray(10) As Integer

    testArray(0) = 125
    testArray(1) = 6
    testArray(2) = 45
    testArray(3) = 15
    testArray(4) = 16
    testArray(5) = 107
    testArray(6) = 108
    testArray(7) = 10
    testArray(8) = 32
    testArray(9) = 45
    testArray(10) = 72

    Dim largestArray() As Integer
    largestArray = GetLargestIndices(testArray, 4)
End Sub
```

Comment: @braceyourself -- I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean that I need to find the index only...not the value..
if I have 6,3,7,9,2,4 as values then my output should return 0,2,3,5(i.e. indices of four largest elements)

Comment: @braceyourself Right, I reworked it.  You can pass it the number of indices you want returned.

Comment: can you please tell me how will I call the function

Comment: @braceyourself -- I made another update to the function itself, so re-copy it.  I added a test sub to show you how it's used.

Comment: I used this but the function is returning only two largest elements and other two elements are not one of the largest elements

Comment: @braceyourself -- Did you see my latest comment?

Comment: Sorry for the conusion....I had seen your comments already and code is working fine....thanks a lot for speding time on this one. :)

Comment: @roryap...sorry for interruption again...but the above code is not working when array is like below
    testArray(0) = 125
    testArray(1) = 6
    testArray(2) = 88
    testArray(3) = 23
    testArray(4) = 16
    testArray(5) = 107
    testArray(6) = 108
    testArray(7) = 10
    testArray(8) = 32
    testArray(9) = 45
    testArray(10) = 72

Comment: I tried this version, but I am getting run-time error 9 when the first element in the array is not the highest

Comment: I made a minor change in your code
For k = 0 To j
The loop should run j-1 times, not j times, else we will get runtime error, thanks for the immense help with the code :) you have been really helpful